# Finding the CFG (Context Free Grammar) of a language

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Can we write a CFG (Context Free Grammar) for the set of all non-empty string whose length are multiple of 3 on the alphabet $ \Sigma = \{A,R,G,C\} $

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. (If you asked this question honestly, not just to make someone else to do your homework, then k.stm's hint should be enough to get you moving.)

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. A non-empty word whose length is a multiple of $3$ has either length $3$ or consist of a non-empty word whose length is $3$ and a non-empty word whose length is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I know that, but I want to construct a CFG for that language.

Comment: @danishjo It’s a trivial statement, of course, but it should help you thinking about the variables you have to introduce and which rules to apply to them. Did you already try to construct a grammar?